# RTF Document with Page Break and Textboxes or Tables

Tags: document, rtf

I am trying to create an RTF Document consisting of 2 pages and some textboxes and/or tables.

So far, I have written the following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Arial;}}
\paperw14173\paperh14173\margl1701\margr1701\margt2268\margb2268

\pard\plain\f0\fs53

\phpg\pvpg\posx4500\posy6000\absw7000\f0\fs53 Text Box 1 on Page 1 Line 1
\par Text Box 1 on Page 1 Line 2

\par\pard Paragraph 1 on Page 1
\par Paragraph 2 on Page 1


\page\f0\fs53


\par\pard\phpg\pvpg\posx4500\posy6000\absw7000\f0\fs53 Text Box 1 on Page 2 Line 1
\par Text Box 1 on Page 2 Line 2

\par\pard\phpg\pvpg\posx8000\posy8000\absw7000\f0\fs53 Text Box 2 on Page 2 Line 1
\par Text Box 2 on Page 2 Line 2


\par\pard Paragraph 1 on Page 2
\par Paragraph 2 on Page 2

}
```

The text on the pages as well as the text boxes are displayed correctly. However, in OpenOffice as well as in Microsoft Word, an additional line break is inserted on the beginning of page 2.

How can I change my document so that this line break disappears? I have tried to omit the "\par\pard" at the beginning of the first text box on the second page (like it is working on the first page), but this disturbs the entire page break so that I cannot do that.

I have also tried to write something like {\pard Text\par}, but the whole textbox thing seems not to work with that. Perhaps there is some control word I can use after the "\page" in order to do the same like "\par" but without producing the new line?

Important: No solution with rearranging the content! The same applies to tables that cannot be rearranged in any way. The question only refers to the part after the page break!

Here is another example with tables:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Corbel;}}
{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11905\paperh16838\margl1134\margr1134\margt1134\margb1134
\pard\plain\f0\fs24\cf0\ql\pard
{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D1}\cell\row}
{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D2}\cell\row}
{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D3}\cell\row}

\pard
\par\pard\page\pard\f0\fs24\cf0\ql
\pard

{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C1}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D1}\cell\row}
{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C2}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D2}\cell\row}
{\trowd\clvertalt\cellx2409\clvertalt\cellx4819\clvertalt\cellx7228\clvertalt\cellx9638\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql A3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql B3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql C3}\cell\pard\intbl{\f0\fs24\cf0\ql D3}\cell\row}
\pard

}
```

Here are 2 tables and a page break in between. This page break is properly displayed in OpenOffice, but not in Word. It only works in Word if you put "\par" behind the "\page" but this is producing the empty line in front of the table instead of showing the table at the first position of the second page. If you are only writing \page instead of the construct (with \par and \pard) above, it is even not working in Open Office.

So, I think there must be something missing to make it work. Some control word? Some brackets?

Comment: can you explain why re-arranging the content isnt a valid solution?

Comment: Because it can not be used in each case. For example, when there is a table at the first position of the second page, again the additional line break appears. The paragraphs are only a placeholder to easily demonstrate the problem. I am searching for some keyword that clearly marks the page break or encloses each page or something like that, no matter what content is there on the page. The \page command alone only works if there are no special formatted paragraphs/tables etc on the page...

Comment: @pancho018: I have added another example demonstrating the problem on tables.

Comment: i see, i'll remove my answer. is the problem not that in some cases openoffice and word interpret the rtf differently? have you tried any other rtf readers?

Comment: I have also tried AbiWord. Of course, sometimes the programs are interpreting RTF in different ways, but I could not find any way to make it work without the line break in Word at all - independent from other program interpretations...

Comment: Have you tried using a section break page - `{\sect}\sbkpage`? Or making the `\par` hidden using `\v\par\v0`?